# Why does VBA say "(Not Responding)" even when code is running fine?

Tags: vba, excel

I've run into this issue with many different VBA programs, so I'm thinking I may have some incorrect settings in Excel or the VBA editor. Honestly, I'm pretty clueless after a lot of web searching.

Basically, I'll be running a normal piece of code and the application (both Excel and the VBA Editor) will go into (Not Responding) mode. **However the code is running fine. Once the code is finished, the application will no longer be in non-responsive mode and everything returns to normal**

Really kinda frustrating on users who think something is wrong when really it's just taking a while to run the code.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: To vague description to find out the reason of such of troubles. The most  frequently reason is: there is to many common events which fires each other. Excel does not respond, because it's trying to refresh UI.

Comment: Because VBA is single threaded. The OS can't update the GUI unless you explicitly give it a chance to. `DoEvents` usually does well here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try putting `DoEvents` statements in your code, so that `DoEvents` is executed every so often during a lengthy process.  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/118468/en-us

This will return control to the OS, so that the OS can do what it needs to do while your program is running, and this should prevent the OS from thinking that your program is not responding.

Comment: Thanks! This worked really well and solved the issues.

Comment: Be aware that DoEvents is not an especially elegant way to solve this problem, because it relies on your code frequently yielding control to the OS.  Running on a separate thread is "better", but if this works for your use case, it's the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks - The solution is easy and apropriate for VBA. @EricJ is however right, that a more genral solution is a separate thread. I use a simple progress window while performung calculations. There `DoEvents` is perfect.

Comment: I found out, that it usually is enough to do a repaint of the form in some frequence. So `me.repaint` will also do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I'll be running a normal piece of code and the application (both Excel and the VBA Editor) will go into (Not Responding) mode. However the code is running fine. Once the code is finished, the application will no longer be in non-responsive mode and everything returns to normal

The User Interface is not responding because you are doing a bunch of processing in response to a UI event.

If this is acceptable to you and your users, all's well enough.  If not, consider doing the work on a [background thread](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/150777?wa=wsignin1.0).

Comment: Yes you can.  Added a link to the answer (https://support.microsoft.com/kb/150777?wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: Thanks! I have had luck with the 'DoEvents' described in the other answer. It's nice to learn about calling a background thread. Definitely over my head. Thanks again, its awesome to have this website as a resource.