# How to solve "not responding" when running a single command

Tags: excel, vba

I am running an ODBC call to a database from a VBA Form in Excel.  The VBA form indicates that the process is running, but if the ODBC runs too long (and sometimes reaches the 90-second timeout), I get a "not responding"

Since the ODBC call is a single line of code, I cannot put in DoEvents or any of the usual screen-updating workarounds.
I have read [Why does VBA say "(Not Responding)" even when code is running fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487969/why-does-vba-say-not-responding-even-when-code-is-running-fine) and that indicates I need a second thread.  How do I do this?

```
Call ShowWait("Loading Case Procedures via ODBC", 3)
ShtCPP.AutoFilterMode = False
ShtDocs.AutoFilterMode = False
If ShtCPP.Cells(1, 1) = vbNullString Then ShtCPP.Range("A1:J1") = Array("Date", "Sess", "Thr", "Surgeon", "Case#", "MRN", "Patient", "Procedure", "CMBS", "DocId"): ShtCPP.Range("A1:J1").Font.Bold = True
ShtTL.Cells.Clear
ShtTL.Rows.Delete

vData = Array(Int(Now()), Int(Now()) + 7, vbNullString, "41")
If GetData(Case_Procedures, vData, True) Then
    ShtCPP.Activate
    Application.StatusBar = vbNullString
    Call adjustCPPODBC(ShtTL)
    Call loadCPPODBC(ShtTL)
Else
    MsgBox "Connection failed to collect the procedures." & vbCrLf & _
        "See status on Excel for more information." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "You may need to load Case Procedures from exported report."
    If MsgBox("Do you want to mark the process as completed so it doesn't attempt to re-load from ODBC?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2) = vbYes Then
        ShtTables.Cells(2, 78) = Now()
    End If
End If
ShtCPP.Activate
ShtCPP.AutoFilterMode = False
ShtDocs.AutoFilterMode = False
Call ShowWait(, , False)
```

ShowWait writes text to a frame on my form, complete with doevents and such-like
GetData does all the ODBC things, including loading the data to a sheet and closing the ODBC connection.  Returns `True` if it works, `False` if not (usually due to timeout)

What I am trying to do is create a thread that updates the frame regularly so Excel doesn't go into a "not responding", which it can do, even if the ODBC call eventually succeeds within the 90-second timeout.

Comment: That should be HOW to solve...

Comment: Then why not [edit] it to make the correction, instead of posting a comment?